# How do I map keys and values of a dictionary to json array?

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which I want to map to JSON. The keys and values of dictionaries should be added to each JSON object as values.

```
my_dict = {"Stack":1,"Overflow":2}

my_dict2 = {"name":"","rank":""}
```

Result I want should look like this

```
result = [{"name":"Stack","rank":1},{"name:"Overflow":2}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: my_dict = {"Stack":1,"Overflow":2}
   ...:

In [2]: result = [{"name":k,"rank":v} for k,v in my_dict.items()]

In [3]: result
Out[3]: [{'name': 'Stack', 'rank': 1}, {'name': 'Overflow', 'rank': 2}]
```